# font-awesome with sass in a content css

Tags: css, fonts, sass, font-awesome

I checked few topics I this one is kinda new, I found one similar but not the same case.

So, my project is working perfect with sass and font-awesome.

I am importing the font-awesome scss file:

```
//libs
@import "css/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

And  my sass class I am using

```
&:hover { 
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: $fa-var-android;
}
```

I don't want use font-family: FontAwesome; in every class, it's some way to use just like that?

```
&:before {
    content: $fa-var-android;
}
```

Or even better: just the unicode?

```
&:hover {
    content: '\f26e';
}
```

I tried but did not work, someone can give me a help?

Thank you.

Comment: you need to add font family otherwise it will not work

Comment: you can do it this way if you want: `&:hover, &:before, & { font-family: FontAwesome }`

Comment: thanks for the comments, but how i can do this, any example? i want stop use font-family : FontAwesome in my classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I am agree with this answers above but these just apply in few classes not in all my css. understand?

so I found a better way to do this just like that:

```
body {
  font-family:  FontAwesome,Helvetica;
}
```

so like that I can use the unicode and the variables and I don't need write font-family in my classes.

```
&:before {
    content: $fa-var-android;
}


&:hover {
    content: '\f26e';
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution use a common class for the font family.

**HTML**

```
<div class="a b">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.a{
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
.b:before{
  content: '\f26e';
}
.b:hover:before{
  content: '\f2a3';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
&:hover {
content: '\f26e';
}
&:before {
content: '\f003';
}
&:hover, &:before {
font-family: FontAwesome
}
```

So you can add all the classes and pseudo-classes you want after commas and include the font family in one go!

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a `mixin` for that purpose, and in that `mixin` you include the FontAwesome `family-font` and the `content` variable:

```
$icon: 'bar';
$icon-2: 'baz';

@mixin fa($icon){
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: $icon;
}

.foo{
  @include fa($icon);

  &:before{
    @include fa($icon-2);
  }
}
```

And the output:

```
.foo {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "bar";
}

.foo:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "baz";
}
```